# Automatic resize photo issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've found [this](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/options.html) amazing plugin called Flickity, passing through the styling options I've managed to create synced carousel with images.

The issue I can't resolve is how to make images to resize according to device width. I am implementing it to work with kind of horizontal scrolling page. How should I go about this?

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNXrJL)

**HTML**

```
<div class="gallery gallery-nav js-flickity gallerysub"
  data-flickity-options='{ "asNavFor": ".gallery-main", "contain": true, "pageDots": false, "imagesLoaded": true, "percentPosition": false, "prevNextButtons": false, "cellAlign": "left"}'>
  <div class="nav" > <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/u7fo6xssj/image.jpg"></div>
  <div class="nav" > <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/z8n28b08z/image.jpg"></div>
  <div class="nav" > <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/4sh5a6epv/image.jpg"></div>
  <div class="nav" > <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/52ontitc3/image.jpg"></div>
</div>

<div class="gallery gallery-main js-flickity gallerymain"  data-flickity-options='{"freeScroll": true, "wrapAround": true, "prevNextButtons": false, "pageDots": false, "imagesLoaded": true, "percentPosition": false}'>
  <div class="for" > <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/u7fo6xssj/image.jpg"></div>
  <div class="for" > <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/z8n28b08z/image.jpg"></div>
  <div class="for" > <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/4sh5a6epv/image.jpg"></div>
  <div class="for" > <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/52ontitc3/image.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flickity-enabled {
  position: relative;
}

.flickity-enabled:focus { outline: none; }

.flickity-viewport {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.flickity-slider {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* draggable */

.flickity-enabled.is-draggable {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
          tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}

.flickity-enabled.is-draggable .flickity-viewport {
  cursor: move;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: grab;
}

.flickity-enabled.is-draggable .flickity-viewport.is-pointer-down {
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor: grabbing;
}

/* ---- previous/next buttons ---- */

.flickity-prev-next-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
  cursor: pointer;
  /* vertically center */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.flickity-prev-next-button:hover { background: white; }

.flickity-prev-next-button:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #09F;
}

.flickity-prev-next-button:active {
  filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* IE8 */
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.flickity-prev-next-button.previous { left: 10px; }
.flickity-prev-next-button.next { right: 10px; }
/* right to left */
.flickity-rtl .flickity-prev-next-button.previous {
  left: auto;
  right: 10px;
}
.flickity-rtl .flickity-prev-next-button.next {
  right: auto;
  left: 10px;
}

.flickity-prev-next-button:disabled {
  filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* IE8 */
  opacity: 0.3;
  cursor: auto;
}

.flickity-prev-next-button svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
}

.flickity-prev-next-button .arrow {
  fill: #333;
}

/* color & size if no SVG - IE8 and Android 2.3 */
.flickity-prev-next-button.no-svg {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 26px;
}

/* ---- page dots ---- */

.flickity-page-dots {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -25px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
}

.flickity-rtl .flickity-page-dots { direction: rtl; }

.flickity-page-dots .dot {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 8px;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  filter: alpha(opacity=25); /* IE8 */
  opacity: 0.25;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.flickity-page-dots .dot.is-selected {
  filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* IE8 */
  opacity: 1;
}

/* external css: flickity.css */

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body { font-family: sans-serif; }



.gallery-main img {
  display: block;
  height: 600px;
}

.gallery-nav img {
  display: block;
  height: 93px;
}

div.for {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.gallerymain {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.gallerysub {
  margin-top: 30px;

}
```

Comment: use media queries within CSS to do the resizing, flickity is already fully responsive `@media screen and (max:width:800px) {  }`

Comment: @Mousey thank you for this advice, I tried it and it works, maybe you suggest how the resize method can be achieved like on this website: http://www.mariotestino.com/photography/portraits/beyonce/. If you will resize window horizontal or vertical you will notice an interesting image behavior.

Comment: that's a wordpress site according to the code, looks like it uses `mt-templates.js` which might be part of a wordpress plug-in -  it actually looks awful on mobile sizes because you need to scroll right to see the images (or that there are more than one). It looks like they are cropping the images, possibly via css/media queries. Image sprites use code showing an image  loaded but only part of it displayed. A vertical image layout would be better for mobiles. There's heaps of good plug-ins with demo pages.  http://jqueryrain.com and http://plugins.jquery.com have lots.

Comment: more resources on responsive web design -  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/responsive-design/info